# How can I access Data Class Properties created from JSON in Kotlin/Android

Tags: android, kotlin, object, retrofit

I am just getting started with Android/Kotlin and I am having issues with something very basic. I use retrofit to return JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": "45837",
    "date_time": "2022-02-02 12:50:06",
    "pool_filter_status": "0",
    "pool_temperature": "97.59",
    "target_temperature": "97.3",
    "status_changed": "1"
  }
]
```

In my viewmodel class, I have the following function that does retrieve the code from the server:

```
...

   private val _pooldata = MutableLiveData<List<PoolData>>()
   val pooldata: LiveData<List<PoolData>> = _pooldata

...

private fun getPoolData() {
        
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _status.value = PoolApiStatus.LOADING
            try {
                _pooldata.value = PoolDataApi.retrofitService.getPoolData()
                _status.value = PoolApiStatus.DONE
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _status.value = PoolApiStatus.ERROR
     
            }
     
        }
     
    }
```

For what its worth, its always just a single JSON object (though its in a single element array)

My really dumb question is how to access the properties of the data object / returned JSON.

If I log _pooldata.value.toString(), I just get:

```
[PoolData(id=45833, date_time=2022-02-02 12:30:02, pool_filter_status=1, pool_temperature=96.91, target_temperature=97.3, status_changed=0)]
```

I am just trying to understand Kotlin "by doing" at this point, but I don't understand how to access those values (id, date_time, etc). its not _pooldata.id.value, _pooldata[0].id.value etc.

The data class is setup as:

```
data class PoolData(
    val id: String,
    val date_time: String,
    val pool_filter_status: String,
    val pool_temperature: String,
    val target_temperature: String,
    val status_changed: String
)
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the json returns an array then is normal to have a list of one object but, if you know that the json always will contains one object you can use yourListResult.first().  Another option is to use firstOrNull.  And is better to create a repository layer that maps the data object to a domain object

Comment: Thanks - pooldata.value?.first()?.id.toString() seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving your data class as the data format in which retrofit will save your data and your data class refers only one object.
What you need is an array of data classes representing the PoolData.

For example:

```
data class JsonFromApi(val headers: String , listOfPoolData: List<PoolData>..etc)
```

From here you will reference this class to access the PoolData like JsonFromApi.listOfPoolData which will be a list and you can then use index numbers to access any element.

For example:

```
JsonFromApi.listOfPoolData[index] // which will be of PoolData type with all defined properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two classes. First for the array and second for the JSON object which is present in the array.

For array

```
class Data : ArrayList<DataItem>()
//Ignore class name
```

For JSON object

```
data class DataItem(
    val date_time: String,
    val id: String,
    val pool_filter_status: String,
    val pool_temperature: String,
    val status_changed: String,
    val target_temperature: String
)
```

If you don't want to create the data class on your own then in the android studio there is a plugin named JSON to Kotlin class.

Visit this link to know more
https://www.instagram.com/p/CW7UNzZj0gv/